# How to add row breaks?

Tags: android

how to add row breaks in android dynamically ?

```
 TableRow tr5 = new TableRow(this);
                    tr5.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    TextView b5 = new TextView(this);
                    b5.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    b5.setText("Hello");



                    tr5.addView(b5);

                    tl.addView(tr5,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this after you generate a row dynamically 
this will add a break dynamically

```
View m1 = new View(this);



                       m1.setBackgroundColor(0xFFCDCDCD);



                      m1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                      tl.addView(m1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(1,1));
```